# Systemd Dependency

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am fairly new to linux and trying to figure out the dependency on for our HID card printer to magtek card swipe.

When our card printer runs into a jam or errors out, the card reader looses function as well, I'm not understanding why this would be the case.

Running:

```
Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
```

Below is the systemd service:

```
    [Unit]
Description=Venus Print Service
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=kiosk
ExecStart=/usr/bin/daemon -n venus-print-server -r -L 60 -o /etc/venus/printServer-output.log -E /etc/venus/printServer-error.log /etc/venus/printServer-run.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with `a systemd dependency` - what does `venus-print-server` do when there is a jam or *error*? How is the card reader at all related to the printer? It's not clear, is it part of the same device?

Comment: This doesn't even seem to have anything to do with Linux. It looks like an error with the device itself. You might be better off asking this question on Superuser and including the make and model of the device.